# T-SQL get months from ranges of date

Tags: t-sql

I have a Table with id and start date and end date. i want insert into another table, end of each month between the start data and end date and the ID, e.g.

```
ID  Start Date  End Date
1   2012-01-01  2012-03-31
2   2012-10-01  2012-12-31
```

Results

```
ID  MONTH END
1   2012-01-31
1   2012-02-29
1   2012-03-31
2   2012-10-31
2   2012-11-30
2   2012-12-31
```

Comment: What database engine?  MySQL?  SQL Server?  Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

This answer makes some assumptions - no end-dates greater than start-dates, but you should see how it works. It creates a recursive union CTE and uses that to figure out the end dates

```
CREATE TABLE #Dates
(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    START_DATE DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL,
    END_DATE DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Dates VALUES ('2012-01-01', '2012-03-31'), ('2012-10-01','2012-12-31')

WITH MONTHS ([ID],[Month],[Date], [End])
AS
(
    SELECT ID, DATEPART(m,START_DATE) AS [Month], START_DATE AS [Date], DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(m,DATEDIFF(m,0,START_DATE)+1,0)) as [End]
    FROM #Dates
    UNION ALL
    SELECT D.ID, DATEPART(m,DATEADD(m,1,[Date])),DATEADD(m,1,[Date]), DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(m,DATEDIFF(m,0,DATEADD(m,1,[Date]))+1,0)) as [End]
    FROM #Dates D
    INNER JOIN  MONTHS M
    ON D.ID = M.ID
    WHERE DATEADD(m,1,[Date]) < [END_DATE]
)



SELECT * 
FROM MONTHS ORDER BY ID, Date

DROP TABLE #Dates
```